# IntelliJ replace value in yaml file when compile

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I've got problem with IntelliJ. How can I add variable in yaml file? I wanna add "{DATE}" variable to my yaml file, and when I compile it the "{DATE}" be replaced with current date?

```
version: {DATE}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it's possible to get IntelliJ IDEA to do this with its default/built-in "make" command. You should be using an actual build tool like Gradle, Maven, Ant, etc.; they can do such replacements and you can have IDEA delegate builds to the build tool.

Good luck.